# What is good measure to compare algorithms?

Tags: c, algorithm, analysis

Well I was reading an article about comparing two algorithms by firstly analyzing them.

My teacher taught me that you can analyze algorithm by directly using number of steps for that algorithm.

for ex:

```
algo printArray(arr[n]){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    write arr[i];
    }
}
```

will have complexity of `O(N)`, where `N` is size of array. and it repeats the for loop for `N` times.

while

```
algo printMatrix(arr,m,n){
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        write arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

will have complexity of `O(MXN)` ~ `O(N^2)` when `M=N`. statements inside `for` are executed `MXN` times.

similarly `O(log N)`. if it divides input into 2 equal parts. and So on.

But according to that article:

The Measures `Execution Time`, `Number of statements` aren't good for analyzing the algorithm.

because:

**`Execution Time`** will be system Dependent and,

**`Number of statements`** will vary with the programming language used.

and It states that

**Ideal Solution** will be to express running time of algorithm as a function of input size `N` that is `f(n)`.

That confused me a little, How can you calculate running time if you consider execution time as not good measure?

Can experts here please elaborate this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already using the "Ideal Solution" with your O(N), O(N^2) etc analysis.  Execution time would be hard to judge, unless you're comparing multiple algorithms on a single platform.  As for lines, the improper analysis would be: "PrintArray has 2 lines in its algorithm" and "PrintMatrix has 3."  O(N) and O(N*M) are the ideal ways of doing it.

Comment: Algorithms are mathematical processes: their implementation might slightly differ across languages but the mathematical operations stay the same. The complexity you're referring to gives you an approximation of the runtime based on the amount of operations it performs. There are more aspects to choosing an algorithm like the memory it takes and whether or not you want amortized time (instead of complexity, which is the worst-case time) but generally the method you describe is used to primarily determine an algorithm's quality.

Comment: You're making a common mistake in concluding that writing to every element of a 2D array is an `O(N^2)` operation.  It is `O(N)` where `N` is the number of elements in the array.  The fact that `N` is, possibly, the square of another number, is irrelevant in this sort of analysis.  If you don't believe this study a bit more and learn that one can't transform algorithms from one complexity class to another by changing the way you count `N`.  If we could do that we'd never use simple scans over 2D arrays because `O(N^2)` is so much worse than `O(N)`; we'd just leave our arrays in 1D.

Comment: Well I'm Just confused whether my teacher is correct or the author of that aricle or both of them? and How?

Comment: @VedantTerkar Your teacher and the author are saying to use the same method (time-complexity).  The only difference is they are using different terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you were saying "complexity of O(N)" that is referred to as "Big-O notation" which is the same as the "Ideal Solution" that you mentioned in your post.  It is a way of expressing run time as a function of input size.

I think were you got confused was when it said "express running time" - it didn't mean express it in a numerical value (which is what execution time is), it meant express it in Big-O notation.  I think you just got tripped up on the terminology.

Comment: Yup. Exactly. So you mean `Running time` and `execution time` aren't same?

Comment: Generally when people use the term "running time" they mean "time complexity".  Execution time refers to the length of time it takes for code to complete execution.  So correct, they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Execution time is indeed system-dependent, but it also depends on the number of instructions the algorithm *executes*.

Also, I do not understand how the number of steps is irrelevant, given that algorithms are analyzed as language-agnostic and without paying any attention to whatever features and syntactic-sugars various languages imply.

The one measure of algorithm analysis I have *always* encountered since I started analyzing algorithms is the *number of executed instructions* and I fail to see how this metric may be irrelevant.

At the same time, complexity classes are meant as an "order of magnitude" indication of how fast or slow an algorithm is. They are dependent of the number of executed instructions and *independent* of the system the algorithm runs on, because by definition an elementary operation (such as addition of two numbers) should take constant time, however large or small this "constant" means in practice, therefore complexity classes do not change. The constants inside the expression for the exact complexity function may indeed vary from system to system, but what is actually relevant for algorithm comparison is the complexity class, as only by comparing those can you find out how an algorithm behaves *on increasingly large inputs* (asymptotically) compared to another algorithm.

Comment: Number if instructions is irrelevant. Consider a loop from 1 to n vs a loop from 1 to n^2. Same number of instructions, vastly different algorithm complexity.

Comment: @mclaassen Tell me how you define an instruction and I will edit my answer accordingly. A for loop is not an instruction in the sense of my answer. Should I use the term "steps" instead?

Comment: Might be better to use the phrase "number of instructions *executed*"

Comment: @webuster Instruction as in assembly instruction generated when compiling the program.

Comment: Alright, edited my answer to account for the definition of "instruction". Of course you are right if instruction means a single assembly instruction, because that has nothing to do with what the machine actually executes. I hope now you understand what I meant (if you didn't in the first place) and de-downvote me.

Comment: Sorry about that, then. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation waves away constants (both fixed cost and constant multipliers). So any function that takes `kn+c` operations to complete is (by definition!) `O(n)`, regardless of `k` and `c`. This is why it's often better to take real-world measurements (profiling) of your algorithms in action with real data, to see how fast they effectively are.

But execution time, obviously, varies depending on the data set -- if you're trying to come up with a general measure of performance that's *not* based on a specific usage scenario, then execution time is less valuable (unless you're comparing all algorithms under the same conditions, and even then it's not necessarily fair unless you model the majority of possible scenarios, and not just one).

Big-O notation becomes more valuable as you move to larger data sets. It gives you a rough idea of the performance of an algorithm, *assuming reasonable values for `k` and `c`*. If you have a million numbers you want to sort, then it's safe to say you want to stay away from any `O(n^2)` algorithm, and try to find a better `O(n lg n)` algorithm. If you're sorting three numbers, the theoretical complexity bound doesn't matter anymore, because the constants dominate the resources taken.

Note also that while the number of statements a given algorithm can be expressed in varies wildly between programming languages, the number of constant-time steps that need to be executed (at the machine level for your target architecture, which is typically one where integer arithmetic and memory accesses take a fixed  amount of time, or more precisely are *bounded* by a fixed amount of time). It is this bound on the maximum number of fixed-cost steps required by an algorithm that big-O measures, which has no direct relation to actual running time for a given input, yet still describes roughly how much *work* must be done for a given data set as the size of the set grows.

Answer (score 2):

In comparing algorithms, execution speed is important as well mentioned by others, but other factors like memory space are crucial too.

Memory space also uses order of complexity notation.

Code could sort an array in place using a bubble sort needing only a handful of extra memory O(1).   Other methods, though faster, may need O(ln N) memory.

Other more esoteric measures include code complexity like [Cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and [Readability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming#Readability_of_source_code)

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, computer science measures algorithm effectivity (speed) by the number of comparisons or sometimes data accesses, using "Big O notation". This is so, because the number of comparisons (and/or data accesses) is a good mathematical model to describe efficiency of certain algorithms, searching and sorting ones in particular, where O(log n) is considered the fastest possible in theory.

This theoretic model has always had several flaws though. It assumes that comparisons (and/or data accessing) are what takes time, and that the time for performing things like function calls and branching/looping is neglectible. This is of course nonsense in the real world.

In the real world, a recursive binary search algorithm might for example be extremely slow compared to a quick & dirty linear search implemented with a plain for loop, because on the given system, the function call overhead is what takes the most time, not the comparisons.

There are a whole lot of things that affect performance. As CPUs evolve, more such things are invented. Nowadays, you might have to consider things like data alignment, instruction pipe-lining, branch prediction, data cache memory, multiple CPU cores and so on. All these technologies make traditional algorithm theory rather irrelevant.

To write the most effective code possible, you need to have a specific system in mind and you need in-depth knowledge about said system. Fortunately, compilers have evolved a lot too, so a lot of the in-depth system knowledge can be left to the person who implements a compiler port for the specific system.

Generally, I think many programmers today spend far too much time pondering about program speed and coming up with "clever things" to get better performance. Back in the days when CPUs were slow and compilers were terrible, such things were very important. But today, a good, modern programmer focus on making the code bug-free, readable, maintainable, re-useable, secure, portable etc. It doesn't matter how fast your program is, if it is a buggy mess of unreadable crap. So deal with performance when the need arises.